# Not showing installed targets for active toolchain in rustup show

Tags: ubuntu, rust

when running this command on my ubuntu 20.04 `rustup show` , this is the result [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5QWI.png)

How can I see installed targets for active toolchains like this one?

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvoTJ.png)

Comment: rustup toolchain list  for targets rustup target list

Comment: [Do not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Rustup will only show sections when there are multiple available. For example, if you only have one toolchain, `stable`, and one target, `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, this is what you'd see:

```
> rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/kmdreko/.rustup

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
```

But if you have two targets available, like you ran `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`, then you'd see the "installed targets for active toolchain" section:

```
> rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/kmdreko/.rustup

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
```

And if you have two toolchains available, like you then ran `rustup toolchain add nightly`, then you'd see the "installed toolchains" section as well:

```
> rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/kmdreko/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
```

Comment: Hey i ran this command , "rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly"  which resulted in "info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date
"

but still the installed targets for active toolchain is not showing.

Comment: @ChiragBaghasingh you've installed the `wasm32` target for the `nightly` toolchain, but your *active* toolchain is `stable`, so it won't show up. You can use `rustup +nightly show` to get `rustup show` output for the `nightly` toolchain. You can also change the default or set an override if you wish: [Overrides - The rustup book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html)